# Can I create array based on field names that exist in PDF?

Tags: arrays, pdf, field

I am trying to count the number of a specific field which is not empty and would like to use an array to store the field names based on whether they exist in the PDF form.

My code looks like this so far and it works as long as the field names in the array exists, if that field does not exist then the code breaks.

The SiteDeficiency_DeficiencyNumber_# could have 0 instances or anywhere up to 50 instances or so.

I did find that you can check if a name exists with this code but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help is appreciated. I have coded simple things but maybe this is just too advanced for me.

**This is what my code looks like so far:**

```
var aFields = new Array("SiteDeficiency_DeficiencyNumber_1",
"SiteDeficiency_DeficiencyNumber_2",
"SiteDeficiency_DeficiencyNumber_3",
"SiteDeficiency_DeficiencyNumber_4",
"SiteDeficiency_DeficiencyNumber_5",
"SiteDeficiency_DeficiencyNumber_6");

var count = 0;

for (i = 0; i < aFields.length; i++) { 
    if (this.getField(aFields[i]).valueAsString != "") count++ 
}
```

event.value = count;

**I tried incorporating this too**

```
if(document.forms[0].SiteDeficiency_DeficiencyNumber_1)
{
 ...
}
```

I would really like the array at the beginning to populate with only the SiteDeficiency_DeficiencyNumber_# fields that exist and then have the array looped through to count which fields are not blank.

I tried doing this but still does not work.

```
var aFields = [];
for(i = 1; i <101; i++)
{
    if(document.forms[0].("SiteDeficiency_DeficiencyNumber_"+i).valueAsString.length > 0) //Checks if field exists
    {
        aFields.push("SiteDeficiency_DeficiencyNumber_"+i); //adds field name to array
    }
}
```

var count = 0;

```
for (a = 0; a < aFields.length; a++) { 
    if (this.getField(aFields[a]).valueAsString != "") count++ //counts field if not empty
```

}

event.value = count;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++)
{
    if (this.getNthFieldName(i).indexOf("SiteDeficiency_DeficiencyNumber")!= -1){ 
        if (this.getField(this.getNthFieldName(i)).valueAsString != "")
            count = count +1
    }
}
event.value = count;
```

The first if statement will check if name of the field contain string `SiteDeficiency_DeficiencyNumber`. If SiteDeficiency_DeficiencyNumber is present in the field naem then it will check the field value and increment accordingly.

Don't forget to upvote! let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Great let me know if you need anything else!